# Errors after upgrading sitecore from 8.1 to 8.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

After upgrading sitcore the log is throwing some exception as per below

> 16644 17:36:50 INFO  [Sitecore Mvc]: Registered area : AppCenter
>   ManagedPoolThread #14 17:36:50 INFO  Cache created:
>   'ItemCloningRelations' (max size: 50MB, running total: 3237MB) 8796
>   17:36:50 ERROR [Index=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web,
>   Crawler=SitecoreItemCrawler, Database=web] Root item could not be
>   found: {09CF9489-8F71-4A16-B707-4F013D8CDEFB}. ManagedPoolThread #14
>   17:36:51 ERROR Exception Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)    at (Object ,
>   Object[] )    at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
>   pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more errors
>   occurred. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`2 body)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1
>   indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message:
>   [Index=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web, Crawler=SitecoreItemCrawler,
>   Database=web] Root item could not be found:
>   {09CF9489-8F71-4A16-B707-4F013D8CDEFB}. Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
>   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.get_RootItem()    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsAncestorOf(Item item)
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsExcludedFromIndex(IIndexableUniqueId
>   indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext,
>   Boolean checkLocation)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId,
>   IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions
>   indexingOptions)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__10(IndexableInfo
>   info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object
>   )

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration for your index "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web" it seems that the item "{09CF9489-8F71-4A16-B707-4F013D8CDEFB}" which is your index root item doesn't exist in the web database, a Sitecore publish can solve the issue if this item exist in your master database.

Comment: Then you need to go to the related configuration file and change this to an existing item. You can go to /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx page and look for "sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web" where you can find the related file.

Comment: The file name should be "Sitecore.Marketing.Solr.Index.Web.config" and the value in my 8.2 clean instance for the root item is {09CF9489-8F71-4A16-B707-4F013D8CDEFB}.